# Moving tick marks to inside of axis in raw.means.plot2

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

I'm formatting figures for a journal that requires that tick marks be inside the axis. For my first plot using base graphics, I've found that I can use this:

```
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg, tck = 0.02)
```

[image: Plot with tick marks inside axis]

My second plot, however, uses raw.means.plot2 from the plotrix package, and I can't figure out how to get the tick marks to move to the inside of the x axis. I've looked through the plotrix documentation, but I can't seem to find anything on this. For example, I'd like to move the tick marks to the inside of both the x and y axes on this plot, but `tck=0.02` only moves the tick marks on the y axis.

```
mtcars$ID <- seq(1,32)
library('plotrix')
raw.means.plot2(mtcars, col.id="ID",col.offset="cyl", col.x="am", col.value="mpg", tck=0.02)
```

[image: Plot with tick marks only inside y axis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If passing inside the function doesn't work, the next thing to try is a call to `par` *before* plotting.

```
library('plotrix')
mtcars$ID <- seq(1,32)
par(tck = .02)
raw.means.plot2(mtcars, col.id="ID",col.offset="cyl", col.x="am", col.value="mpg")
```

[image]

And note that after plotting `par('tck')` is still `0.02`, so you can use

```
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(stuff)
plot(stuff)
par(op)
```

to return to previous state. Or `graphics.off()` to clear all plots and reset to defaults

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the xaxis and then add one manually

```
raw.means.plot2(mtcars, col.id="ID",col.offset="cyl", col.x="am", col.value="mpg", xaxis = FALSE, tck = 0.02)
axis(1, tck = 0.02)
```